# Why String "\"[]\"" is a valid json?

Tags: java, json, jackson, fastjson

Why fastjson and Jackson both judge the string `"\"[]\""` a valid JSON?

```
@Test
public void validJSON() {
    String jsonString1 = "\"[]\"";
    System.out.println("fastjson: " + JSON.isValid(jsonString1));

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        JsonNode jsonNode1 = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString1);
        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flag = false;
    }
    System.out.println("jackjson: " + flag);
}
```

result:

```
fastjson: true
jackjson: true
```

I want to know why `"\"[]\""` is a valid JSON string.

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the example boils down to - `"literary whatever you want here"`. Your variable `jsonString1` holds the value - `"[]"` (the quotation marks *are* part of the json!). The [specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says that (almost) anything enclosed in double quotes is a valid string, the rest should be escaped to be part of the string. Check [this](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) as well.

From the specification (2.5.  Strings):

> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with quotation marks.

So, the value is a string and a valid json.

Comment: I wonder why this got 2 upvotes, as this answer is - to say the least - somewhat misleading. Not any string is valid JSON, an the example in the question boils down to "it is an empty array and thus valid JSON"

Comment: @GyroGearless You are missing the escaped quotes in the example in question - the actual json stored in `jsonString1` is `"[]"`, which is a string, it's not `[]`, which is array. And as long special characters are escaped, which I have written, anything enclosed in double quotes (`"`) is valid string (ok, I suppose there *may* be some characters, which may break this, but I can't think of any atm).

Comment: @GyroGearless In addition, in this context _"any string"_ should IMHO be read as _"any syntactically valid string according to the JSON specification"_. What constitutes a string or not is contextual.

Comment: Nope. A String is not a VALID json.....Try in every JSON Validator online and if you put "hello baby" the validation won't pass. Instead the "[]" (including quotes) let the validation check to PASS.

Comment: @emandt tried the first three validators, Google found, and all three agree that `"hello baby"` is valid JSON. Don’t know what *you* tried.

Comment: @emandt to spoonfeed further, [first result](https://jsonlint.com/?json=%22hello%20baby%22), [second result](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/?process=true&data=%22hello%20baby%22)…

Comment: @emandt I don't know which validators you tried, all I found agree that `"whatever"` is valid json. But more importantly, the specification, which I have linked, under `2.5 Strings` declares that a string begins and ends with quotation marks (double quotes), which means that `"something"` is a string **and** valid json.